# Git submodules fail to authenticate to bitbucket

Tags: git, jenkins, git-submodules, ssh-keys, private-key

I'm pulling repository from bitbucket using ssh credentials with private key

Project contains some git submodules, here's how I set up to pull them as well:
[image]

However the build fails as the permission is denied during `git submodule update`

```
 > /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git submodule update --init --recursive wallets
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/opt/bitnami/git/bin/git submodule update --init --recursive wallets" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: Cloning into '/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/wallet-core/wallets'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

However the repository itself was checked out without problems. Both repositories belong to the same project and team for which the private key is configured and added to jenkins, so I assume that chekout and submodule procedures don't use the same authentification method. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was simple as checking the "Use credentials from default remote of parent repository" box

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules <Mirror URL>/git/Repository.git
```

It does clone the submodule but the problem of authentication still exist.